# Getting Branch Location using Account/Routing Number in US/Canada

Tags: united-states, canada, banking

Are there any ways to retrieve a branch's address or relative location using the Account or Routing number of an individual account in the United States or Canada?

Are there any publicly exposed APIs for this or is it mandatory to go through a bank's individual locator to find this out?

Comment: This is _too broad_ a question especially when even the country is not specified.

Comment: Is branch information really included in those numbers? I can't think of any good reason it would be, since the accounts exist at bank level rather than branch level. (The credit unions I've used certainly don't include location information in these numbers.)

Answer (score 5):

Man, this one certainly took me a good while to find. (I work in payments processing, so I figured it would be easier).

There is a website, the [Federal Reserve E-Payments Routing Directory](http://www.fededirectory.frb.org/download.cfm), which provides this data in a fixed-width column format, and they provide the file format so that you can parse it, as well. I'd advise against re-distributing this information, though. Routing numbers and the scheme used to create them are considered copyrighted works by the American Bankers Association, and you don't have license to distribute their copyrighted material.

Because this data changes fairly often, you should check the site often for updates.

Comment: Can't wait to tell my landlord that I have to stop sending her a check each month for fear of infringing my bank's copyright. :)

Comment: @dg99 Just thought I'd note it, since websites have been taken down because of re-publishing this publicly-accessible information

Answer (score 1):

For Canadian banks, since there aren't many, you can use their own websites. Scotiabank offers a "search by transit number" option (unless their I'm-smarter-than-you-website thinks you're on a phone or tablet) and so do CIBC and TD (I got bored of checking after 3.) Generally you have to try to search by address first, and when that doesn't work you get a more advanced search page that includes a field for transit number.

I realize that the huge volume of US banks may make it less of an option to search their sites, but since the question asked "US and Canada" and Noah's answer will only cover US banks, I thought I'd fill in the gap. And if you know what bank it is, using their site may be an option even in the US.

Comment: The most common resource I found for US-based banks were actually just custom google searches, since most banks publish their ABA Routing Transit Number on their websites for ease of access. Thanks for providing some coverage on the Canadian side!